# Woocommerce - Add custom checkout field to customer new account email

Tags: woocommerce, custom-fields

I am trying to display the "billing_gender" custom field I have added to my checkout form to the customer new account notification email.

The field is correctly saved to the database but it is shown empty in the new account email.

Other user meta fields (phone, ...) work but not my custom checkout field.

I guess it is saved to late in the user meta information but I really can't figure it out :

Here is my code :

functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'divi_override_checkout_fields' );

function divi_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);

// Custom gender field
$fields['billing']['billing_gender'] = array(
    'type'     => 'select',
    'class'    => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
    'label'    => __( 'Title', 'divi-ultimate'),
    'required' => true,
    'priority' => 3,
    'options'  => array(
        ''           => __( 'Select title', 'divi-ultimate' ),
        'male'       => __( 'Mr', 'divi-ultimate' ),
        'female'     => __( 'Mrs', 'divi-ultimate' )
    ),
);

return $fields;
}

// Gender select default value

add_filter( 'default_checkout_billing_gender', 'checkout_billing_gender',10,2 );

 function checkout_billing_gender($value) {
if ( is_user_logged_in()){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $value = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'billing_gender', true );
}
return $value;
}


//* Update the order meta with fields values

 add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'divi_select_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 10, 2);

 function divi_select_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {

if ($_POST['delivery-shop']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'delivery-shop', esc_attr($_POST['delivery-shop']));
if ($_POST['billing_gender']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_gender', esc_attr($_POST['billing_gender']));

 }

 //* Update the user meta with gender value

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 'divi_save_extra_user_fields', 10, 2 );

 function divi_save_extra_user_fields($customer_id) {
 if (isset($_POST['billing_gender'])) {
     update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_gender',  esc_attr($_POST['billing_gender']) );
 }
 }
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the customer-new-account.php file :

```
$user = get_user_by('login', $user_login );

if (!empty($user)) {
$gender = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'billing_gender', true);
$lastname = $user->last_name;
$user_email = $user->user_email;
}

if( !empty($gender) && !empty($lastname) ) {
printf( esc_html__( 'Dear ' . $gender . ' %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $lastname ) );
}
else {
    printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $email ) );
} ?>
```